# Selecting the next line in a file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to extract information from a *txt* file. Particularly I need the line that is immediately beneath the line that starts with the number (71). Currently, I'm selecting the line that starts with 71 and deleting the line feed by hand in the txt file. How can I select the line that follows the one that starts with 71 automatically? I'm a complete beginner, I apologize if it is a dumb question.

```
fhand = input('Ingrese nombre de archivo: ')
file = open(fhand, encoding='utf8')

pais = dict()
provincia = dict()

for line in file :
    if line.startswith('(71)') : 
      line = line.rstrip()
      lista = line.split(' ')
      pais[lista[-1]] = pais.get(lista[-1], 0) + 1
      if pais == 'AR':
        provincia[lista[-2]] = provincia.get(lista[-2], 0 ) + 1    

print(pais)
print(provincia)
print(count, cuenta)
```

I'm manually deleting the line feed in order to obtain the information I need. I would like to automate this process.

Comment: First of all, you should use the `with` statement to read the whole file first, and to delete the line feed you can do `line.replace('\n', '')` (on each line), for the rest you are close

Comment: Thank you very much CreepyRacoon for your answer.